# Split string with zsh as in Python

Tags: string, split, zsh

In python:

```python
s = '1::3'
a = s.split(':')
print(a[0]) # '1' good
print(a[1]) # '' good
print(a[2]) # '3' good
```

How can I achieve the same effect with `zsh`?

The following attempt fails:

```zsh
string="1::3"
a=(${(s/:/)string})
echo $a[1] # 1
echo $a[2] # 3 ?? I want an empty string, as in Python
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The solution is to use the `@` modifier, as indicated in [the zsh docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags):

```zsh
string="1::3"
a=("${(@s/:/)string}") # @ modifier
```

By the way, if one has the choice of the delimiter, it's much easier and less error prone to use a newline as a delimiter. The right way to split the lines with zsh is then:

```zsh
a=("${(f)string}")
```

I don't know whether or not the quotes are necessary here as well...

Comment: Thanks. Are you able explain how it works though, so many brackets is making it confusing!

Comment: If you're trying to split on slashes, the original `/`s can be replaced with `|`s, it seems (e.g. `a=(${(s|/|)string}")`). I can't seem to find any documentation on this, though, so maybe there's some subtle behaviour change.

Comment: @Harry, the linked documentation says this: "Any character, or the matching pairs ‘(...)’, ‘{...}’, ‘[...]’, or ‘<...>’, may be used in place of a colon as delimiters, …." In Olivier's code, the character "used in place of a colon" was slash; in yours, it's vertical bar. So, no behavior change.

Comment: This worked correctly in the command line, but when I moved it into a function, I got the "unrecognized modifier" error, any idea?

Comment: So much easier to grok than the IFS bash equivalent.  Thanks

Comment: why need the `@` in the second example it goes without?

Comment: the second approach is not working for me

Answer (score 10):

This will work in both zsh (with `setopt shwordsplit` or `zsh -y`) and Bash (zero-based arrays):

```
s="1::3"
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=':'
a=(${s})
IFS="$saveIFS"
```

Comment: This worked for me on the command line but would not work for me in a function even though I made sure shwordsplit was set.  I'm not sure why it didn't.

Comment: @ws_e_c421: It works for me in a function in zsh and Bash. You didn't say which you are using. You should be able to `echo ${a[1]}` and `echo ${a[3]}` and get `1` and `3`, respectively (the subscripts should be `0` and `2` for Bash). If it's short, post here what you tried and how exactly it failed. If it's a little longer, post a new question and link to it here.

Comment: IMHO you should scope environment variable changes like that, e.g. `IFS=':' cmd args...`, so the change is coupled with the context/lifespan where it's expected/used. Then it's Not Your Job to know the prior values you aren't using, or to manage or recreate the outside environment, etc. - instead they clean themselves up.

Comment: @JohnP: That kind of scoping doesn't work with a variable assignment (in this case creating an array from a scalar). And another kind of scoping, using a subshell, doesn't work here because the array being created would also be scoped to the subshell and thus unavailable later. But your point is valid in contexts where it's useful.

Comment: Unless you use the value in the subshell, right? I guess aiming for side effects kind of defeats the purpose of encapsulation. Point taken about the variable assignment, I didn't realize why that was. I had guessed that it was just a technical parsing quirk, like one assignment with a trailing subexpression induces the next to have one, or something like that.

Comment: Aha! Try this: `f(){ a=(${s}); echo "$a, $s, '$IFS'" }; IFS=':' s='1::3' f; echo "$a, $s, '$IFS'"` The results are... problematic. Both IFS and s are scoped to f, so f's echo sees the given values, and the other echo has empty s and original IFS. Meanwhile `a` is implicitly global, so the outer echo gets the value from `s` it can't see directly. But the value is '1::3'. I'm too tired to tell if I made a dumb mistake, any ideas?

Comment: @JohnP: There are a couple of small issues with your example: There needs to be a semicolon before the space and closing curly brace at the end of your function. And echoing `$a` only outputs the first element of the array. Using `${a[@]}` will output the entire array. But using `declare -p` is better when testing since it reveals the structure of arrays: `unset a s; f(){ a=(${s}); declare -p a s IFS; }; IFS=':' s='1::3' f; declare -p a s IFS` . Additionally, you can get a clearer representation of `IFS` by doing this: `printf '%q\n' "$IFS"` . The process of setting vairiable values...

Comment: ...for a command's environment isn't a parsing quirk - it's an [intentional design choice](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01). I'm not sure I understand what you're saying about `a`, `s` and the value `1::3`, but the behavior of the (corrected) example for me is completely as expected. Note that in a real script if the value if `s` is to be used outside the function then it shouldn't be limited to the execution environment of the function and only the (temporary) assignment of `IFS` would be. So, ...

Comment: ...perhaps `unset a; s='1::3'; f(){ a=(${s}); declare -p a s IFS; }; IFS=':' f; declare -p a s IFS`

Comment: It was that inside f, it showed `IFS=':'`, and yet, `a=(${s})` did not split s by ':'.

Comment: @JohnP: It does for me. This is the output I see from the echo inside your function (with the missing semicolon added): `1, 1::3, ':'`. The `1` is the first element of the array `a` which is the result of splitting `s`. See my earlier comments regarding better ways to output arrays. Something I didn't mention earlier is using `local IFS=':'` inside a function to limit the scope (but that doesn't apply to your original point).

Comment: Wow, then something's wrong on my end. When I `echo $a` or `echo "$a"` I get all of the elements, not the first element, no matter how they're assigned. Adding the semicolon to my example doesn't appear to change anything (not sure why it would.) Oh, and f from your example using declares outputs `typeset -g -a a=( 1::3 )`, `export s=1::3`, and `export IFS=:` - it definitely isn't splitting on ':' like it claims.

Comment: @JohnP: Oops, no, everything I've said is regarding Bash. I think you may want to take a look at Olivier Verdier's answer using the `@` modifier without `IFS` (or you may need `setopt shwordsplit` as I indicate in mine).