# ZSH 5.05 string split on null

Tags: python, bash, split, zsh

As noted by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930238/split-string-with-zsh-as-in-python), ZSH squeezes adjacent separators in a string split by default. Now, in ZSH 5.05, the supplied fix does not work.

```
Hexagon% string="1::3"
Hexagon% setopt interactive_comments
Hexagon% a=("${(s/:/)string}") # notice the quotes
Hexagon% 
Hexagon% echo $a[1] # 1, good
1
Hexagon% echo $a[2] # nothing, good
3
Hexagon% echo $a[3] # 3, good
```

As you can see, my result does not match the one recorded on a previous ZSH. How can I emulate this functionality, and better yet, is there a portable way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following in `zsh`:

```
IFS=: read -r -A a <<<"$string"
```

- `-A` reads the input into an *array*, named `a` in this case.
- `IFS=:` (localized to the command) defines `:` as the separator to split the input into fields by - multiple adjacent separators are considered to be enclosing *empty* fields, so `$a[2]` ends up empty.

---

Doing this *portably* gets tricky:

Here's a solution that works on `zsh`, `bash`, and `ksh` - it is NOT POSIX-compliant, however (see below):

```
# Determine the shell-specific option character for `read`;
# [-]A for ksh and zsh, [-]a for bash:
readIntoArrayOptChar='A' && [[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]] && readIntoArrayOptChar='a'

# Read the input string into array `a`, splitting into elements by ':'
IFS=: read -r -$readIntoArrayOptChar a <<<"$string"

# Determine the shell-specific start and end indices for printing
# the array elements in a loop:
# bash and ksh are 0-based, zsh is 1-based (by default).
startNdx=0 endNdx=${#a[@]}
[[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]] && (( ++startNdx, ++endNdx ))

# Print array elements individually.
# Note how the element references are enclosed in {...} for cross-shell 
# compatibility.
for (( i = startNdx; i < endNdx; i++ )); do
  echo "el. $i: ["${a[i]}"]" # -> e.g., in zsh, 1st iteration: 'el. 1: [1]'
done
```

Note:

- Python's `subprocess.call()` with parameter `shell = True` and `os.system()` invoke `sh` by default, where you can rely on *POSIX features only* (and, if the platform is not Unix-like, not even on that).
- The above is NOT POSIX-compliant, primarily because array variables are not part of the POSIX shell-language specification, as @rici points out.
- @rici also points out the *notable absence from `zsh` of the bash/ksh construct* `${!a[@]}` for obtaining the *list of indices* of an array (`a`).

Comment: Thank you so much! I suppose I have just one more detail, `read` is a shell builtin, and therefore no process is started, right? This code is used for some fairly heavy computation and stating a process on every split could slow it down by and order of magnitude.

Comment: @PythonNut: Yes, `read` is a _builtin_ in all 3 shells (`bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`), so no _additional_ process is started, but, of course, the shell itself is a process. How are you invoking the shell? Note that Python module `subprocess` with parameter `shell = True`, and module `os` with `system()` invoke `sh` by default, where you can only rely on _POSIX_ features (and, if the platform is not Unix-like, not even on that).

Comment: @mklement0: `printf %s\\n "${a[@]}"` works on `{ba,k,z}sh` but it's not so easy to include the element index. `paste <(printf %s\\n "${!a[@]}") <(printf %s\\n "${a[@]}")` works only on `{ba,k}sh`; the `zsh` `"${(k)a[@]}"` only works if `a` is associative. But I don't see what's wrong with using the `(s/:/)` flag for splitting.

Comment: @rici: On `zsh` versions `5.0.2` and `5.0.5`, `a=("${(s/:/)string}")` only creates _2_ array elements, because runs of adjacent `:` instances are apparently treated as a _single_ separator, which the OP doesn't want. (The OP suggests that previous `zsh` versions behaved differently - I haven't looked into that.)

Comment: @rici: Thanks for pointing out the differences in obtaining array indices. My answer demonstrates use of explicit numeric indices by adjusting the base index according to the shell. This difference could  be ironed out with `emulate sh` in `zsh` (obviously, with other side effects) - however, that doesn't address the `"${!a[@]}"` issue.  Then again, I'm not even clear on what the portability requirements are. If strict POSIX-compliance is needed, my answer won't work anyway.

Comment: @mklement0: The word "array" precludes strict POSIX-compliance. I read the question as being about `zsh`, since that word appears four times in the question, including the title. (I don't know why there is a `bash` tag, although I wouldn't have seen the question otherwise.) Of course, it's always interesting to compare solutions in other shells.

Comment: @rici: Well, there is also `is there a portable way to do so?` :) Good  point re array variables not being part of the POSIX shell spec. Do you know of a `zsh` equivalent to `"${!a[@]}`?

Comment: @mklement0: The only equivalent I know is the (k) flag, but as I said it only works on associative arrays so its not much use here. You could use something like cat -n

Comment: @rici: Thanks; curiously, `(k)` returns _values_ with _ordinary_ arrays. `cat -n` is convenient for generating index lists for _contiguous_ arrays starting at 1, but not for _sparse_ ones. In fact, I couldn't even _manually_ replicate the behavior of `${!a[@]}` (which for sparse arrays in bash/ksh only returns indices of _defined_ elements): While `zsh` at least allows you to find the _maximum_ index via `$#a` (note how that differs from bash/ksh), it doesn't implement true sparse arrays: _all_ elements are implicitly defined, so a test like `[[ -z ${a[i]+defined} ]]` doesn't work.

Comment: @mklement0: as far as I know, that's correct. If you want a sparse array in `zsh`, you need to use an associative array. However, again afaik, there is no built-in way to populate an associative array from a split. So that's all probably grist for a more specific `zsh`-tagged question. (Not *all* elements are defined: only the ones within the range index.)

Comment: @rici Yes, I took us on a tangent; thanks for coming along. Thanks for the clarification re "all" elements - another way of putting it: all elements between 1 (assuming the default base index of 1) and `$#a` (i.e., the highest index ever assigned to) - are implicitly defined. Tangent dismissed. :)

Comment: Thank you both. This has been a very enlightening conversation.

Comment: @PythonNut: My pleasure; now we know that at least _3_ people found it interesting. :)

Answer (score 2):

In zsh version 5.0.2 (and presumably onwards) you can retain empty strings in a split by adding the `@` flag:

```
a=("${(@s/:/)string}")
```

Comment: +1; good to know - definitely the best `zsh` solution (though not portable).